# How can one use the "Add view" dialog in Visual Studio efficiently when working with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, usability

Does anyone else think that the add view dialog in VS is useless or is it just me?

Why is there no search/filtering in there? I can not even paste the type name (without namespace) there to speed up the view creation.

Plus, there are a lot of irrelevant classes there, including classes from all referenced libraries.

Am I missing something or Microsoft never did any usability testing with that??

Is it possible to filter out types/assemblies in the dialog and/or better navigation compared to manually scrolling the combobox with all the types listed? Is it possible to include only types from a particular directory/assembly/namespace? (the ViewModels namespace for example)

---

**EDIT:** As it seems from the answers that there is no usable workaround for this, I have filed a suggestion at Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=507784

Please vote for the suggestion if you find this is an important issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resharper 5.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#web_development) implements this dialog very efficiently, solving all the described problems.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is search/filter, but it's a "starts with" search. Start typing and the list will be filtered.
2. You can paste the type name, but you do need the namespace.
3. No, I don't think you can remove assemblies.

Could it be improved? Sure. Some of your suggestions are good, and you should consider filing [Connect reports](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) for them. Is it useless, IMHO, no.

I tried the dialog in VS2010. As of beta 2, it behaves the same as VS2008, AFAICS. So get your suggestions in soon!

Comment: Thanks Craig. The full namespace prefix is partially useful, at least something. I have filed a suggestion via Connect, please vote for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=507784

Comment: I didn't know you could type in the View Data Class combo to filter it. That helps. Slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly agree with you. While it's not competely useless, tha fact that all the classes from the referenced libraries show up and that it doesn't have a search box make it slow to add a new view. Maybe you could file a wishlist bug report on the ASP.NET MVC site...

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from that there is no usable workaround for this, I have filed a suggestion at [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=507784).

In case anyone else feels that this dialog should be improved, please vote for the suggestion in Connect.