# MVC Add View showing log4net classes, doesn't seem to be showing entity-framework classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After adding log4net reference to my MVC 3 project, I see in the Add View dialog (in an Admin Area) a lot of log4net classes...  Any suggestions on how to prevent them from showing?  Kinda makes the list difficult to navigate.

(Almost seems like this dialog needs a type-search function, ie, type in "prospects" to find my prospects model or EF entity class.)

[image: Add View Dialog showing log4net classes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type in the model class dropdown you should see a list of types filtered that start with what you are typing. You can then select from those types. There is no way to prevent types from appearing in the dropdown thoough.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [How can one use the "Add view" dialog in Visual Studio efficiently when working with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656756/how-can-one-use-the-add-view-dialog-in-visual-studio-efficiently-when-working-w)